# Unexpected characters from escaping apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql, forms, apostrophe, addslashes

I created a form that takes a block of text and inserts it into an SQL database.  I kept getting SQL errors when the user used single quotes.  I added the addslashes() function and everything worked out fine.  But according to w3, php should already be doing this.  Further, when I retrieve the text from the database, all the apostrophes are replaced with � character.

Does anyone know what's happening? I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: check the db encoding , as well as the page encoding on which you are extracting the data

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string` and see if it's still happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

mysql_escape_string() worked.  For the record, addslashes() was turning apostrophes into backticks.   The problem

Answer (score 0):

Use these functions to insert data in db or out from db
These will solve the problem of single quote or double quotes and all special charters.

```
function DBin($string) 
{
    return  trim(htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_QUOTES));
}

function DBout($string) 
{
    $string = trim($string);
    return htmlspecialchars_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES);
}
```